# How to optimize my MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have two tables
Invoice(
  `Id`,
  `Status`,
  `VendorId`,
  `CustomerId`,
  `OrderDate`,
  `InvoiceFor`,
)

InvoiceItem(
  `Id`,
  `Status`,
  `InvoiceId`,
  `ProductId`,
  `PackageQty`,
  `PackagePrice`,
)

here invoice.id=invoiceItem.invoiceId (Foregin key)
and Id fields are primary key (big int)
these tables contains 100000(invoice) and 450000(invoiceItem) rows

---

Now I have to write a query which will return the ledger of invoices where invoice for = 55 or 66 and in a certain date range.
I also have to return a last taken date which will contain the previous taken date of product by that particular customer.

---

The output should be
OrderDate, InvoiceId, CustomerId, ProductId, LastTaken, PackageQty, PackagePrice

---

So I write the following query

```
SELECT a.*, (
    SELECT MAX(ivv.orderdate)
    FROM invoice AS ivv , invoiceItem AS iiv 
    WHERE ivv.id=iiv.invoiceid
    AND iiv.ProductId=a.ProductId AND ivv.CustomerId=a.CustomerId AND ivv.orderDate<a.orderdate
) AS lastTaken FROM (
    SELECT iv.Id, iv.OrderDate, iv.CustomerId, iv.InvoiceFor, ii.ProductId,     
    ii.PackageQty, ii.PackagePrice
    FROM invoice AS iv, invoiceitem AS ii
    WHERE iv.id=ii.InvoiceId 
    AND iv.InvoiceFor IN (55,66)
    AND iv.Status=0 AND ii.Status=0 
    AND OrderDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
    ORDER BY iv.orderdate, iv.Id ASC 
) AS a
```

**But I always got the Time out. How Will I solve the problem???**

the Explain for this query is as follows:
[image]

Comment: What indexes exist for these tables?

Comment: Id is the primary key for both tables

Comment: Is InvoiceItem.InvoiceId indexed?  That would be helpful in almost any situation.

Comment: Yes invoiceid of invoiceitem table is the foregin key which contains the value of id of invoice table

Comment: I believe that MySQL creates index for the foreign key by default.

Answer (score 0):

Create index on OrderDate and InvoiceFor attributes. It should be much faster.

Comment: @G.M.NazmulHossain Type EXPLAIN before select (EXPLAIN SELECT ...) and post output here.

Comment: id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 PRIMARY <derived3> ALL \N \N \N \N 66057 
3 DERIVED iv ALL PRIMARY,NewIndex1,NewIndex2 \N \N \N 73444 Using filesort
3 DERIVED ii ref FK_invoiceitem FK_invoiceitem 9 test1.iv.Id 1 Using where
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY ivv ALL PRIMARY,NewIndex1 \N \N \N 73444 Using where
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY iiv ref FK_invoiceitem FK_invoiceitem 9 test1.ivv.Id 1 Using where

Comment: better check the image
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3857428482034&set=a.1075930066312.2012468.1468041324&type=1&relevant_count=1&ref=nf

Answer (score 0):

Two points about the query itself:

1. Learn to use proper JOIN syntax.  Doing the joins in the `WHERE` clause is like writing questions in Shakespearean English.
2. The `ORDER BY` in the subquery should be outside at the highest level.

However, neither of these are killing performance.  The problem is the subquery in the `SELECT` clause.  i think the problem is that your subquery in the `SELECT` clause is not joining the two tables directly.  Try including `iiv.InvoiceId = ivv.InvoiceId` in, preferably, and `ON` clause.

If that doesn't work, try an indexing strategy.  The following indexes should improve the performance of that subquery:

- An index on InvoiceItem(ProductId)
- An index on Invoice (CustomerId, OrderDate)

This should allow MySQL to run the subquery from indexes, rather than full table scans, which should be a big performance improvement.